# IConnectionPoint::Advise call returned E_NOTIMPL

Tags: visual-c++, com

**Note**:

- No MFC
- No ATL
- Using Visual C++

While attempting a connection between the connection point and the caller's sink, an **E_NOTIMPL** (0x80004001) was returned.

Illustrated below:

```
hresult = pConnection->Advise(
                             pSinkUnk,
                             &dwAdvise);
```

**Question**:

- How did this occur?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694318(VS.85).aspx), it states that connection points that only allow one connection can return `E_NOTIMPL` from its `EnumConnections()` method. Would it be possible that a connection has already been made for this connection point? Maybe this particular implementation returns `E_NOTIMPL` from `Advise()` in this case as well?

Comment: "Would it be possible that a connection has already been made for this connection point?" How would that be possible...?

Comment: Thanks Andy for your help - would it be possible to contact you via e-mail - I'm grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like the connection and/or the object that you want the events of doesn't implement the events interface that you are expecting. If that's your object, maybe verify that your `QueryInterface()` returns an instance of your object for that interface?